# How to return blocked slots where not all slot no's are blocked (i.e. panellist is not dead)

Tags: sql

I have an Inventory fact table. It is built by exploding the stg table against date and so each slot has an record against each date in the date table.

e.g. here I have shown what the table looks like for PanelList 248. It has 3 slots (900 - 902) with slot no from 1 - 3

```
DateID  SlotID  SlotNo  Available   Blocked PanelList
20200922    900 1   1   0   248
20200923    900 1   1   0   248
20200922    901 2   1   0   248
20200923    901 2   1   0   248
20200922    902 3   1   0   248
20200923    902 3   1   0   248
```

Slots can can be blocked. In some cases selective slots of a PanelList is blocked. In other all the slots (i.e. all slot no is blocked. This is when a slot is dead)

I want to query the fact table to return only selective blocked panel, i.e. those PanelLists and SlotIDs who have a blocked slot across one or more slot no but NOT all slot no's (in that case it is dead).

e.g.

```
DateID  SlotID  SlotNo  Available   Blocked PanelList
20200922    900 1   1   0   248
20200923    900 1   1   0   248
20200922    901 2   1   1   248
20200923    901 2   1   1   248
20200922    902 3   1   0   248
20200923    902 3   1   0   248
```

(note: a blocked slot is when the value of Available and Blocked are both 1)

Comment: I tried to insert the table as a table but I could not figure out how to do this on stack. If someone knows a fix to illustrate the table accordingly please do so. Apologies in advance. Please add appropriate tags too. Much appreciated, Shoaib

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.panellist = t.panellist and 
                    t2.available = 1 and t2.blocked = 1
             );
```